# Proj4 string for USGS Bulletin 1532

Tags: coordinate-system, proj, usgs, proj4js, dotspatial

I'm using an application that uses equations from USGS Bulletin 1532 (see source code - line 295: http://docs.ros.org/en/kinetic/api/robot_localization/html/api/navsat__conversions_8h_source.html#l00295). However, I need to use proj4 to do coordinates conversions. So I need to convert from one given projection to the projection used in the equations from USGS Bulletin 1532.

I'm using the C# package DotSpatial.Projections (which is a port for the popular proj4 C++ library to C#). To convert from one coordinate system to another, it receives a proj4 string, such as "+title=WGS 84 (long/lat) +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=degrees". However I don't know how to determine this string for the case of the USGS Bulletin 1532.

How would I define the proj4 string of the equations from USGS Bulletin 1532?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMO you can use the proj.4 tool directly.

Without re-substituting all the terms, your code seems to correspond with the [approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Transverse_Mercator_coordinate_system#Simplified_formulae) from Gerald Everden and John Snyder in the code in [`tmerc.cpp`](https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/blob/master/src/projections/tmerc.cpp) lines 76-116 (`approx_e_fwd` aka. `ll2utm`) and lines (`approx_e_inv` aka. `utm2ll`) lines 154-184.

I found your code base in one of my older Pascal repositories from 1998 which is a port by Kurt Spitzley `Kurt.Spitzley@rz-online.de` of the original C++ code written by Chuck Gantz `chuck.gantz@globalstar.com` also in 1998. A review for this code/equation base was written by John Manchuk in 2009 in the [CCG Annual Report 11, 2009](https://www.ccgalberta.com/ccgresources/report11/2009-410_converting_latlon_to_utm.pdf).

The code base is still present at: http://www.gpsy.com/gpsinfo/geotoutm/.

You could make some speed and code tests for this piece of software archeology ;-).

EDIT:

1. The tool `proj` is a command line tool and has these forward and inverse termini.

So forward is from LL to XY and inverse is XY to LL.

2. The UTM datum is called by:

Forward:

```
proj +datum=UTM +zone=32
```

Inverse:

```
invproj +datum=UTM +zone=32
```

This is a abbrevation for:

```
proj +proj=tmerc +ellps=WGS84 +k=0.9996 +lon_0=9 +lat_0=0 +x_0=500000
```

The next abstaction step is the usage of EPSG's. For further info's have a look at https://epsg.io/32632

Comment: I could partially get what you said. I'm using the C# package DotSpatial.Projections (which is a port for the popular proj4 C++ library to C#). To convert from one coordinate system to another, it receives a proj4 string, such as "+title=WGS 84 (long/lat) +lat_0=0 +lon_0=0 +proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +units=degrees". However I don't know how to determine this string for the case of the  USGS Bulletin 1532. Do you have any suggestions for it.

Comment: @Samuel see EDIT: